# Can't add documents to lunr index after assignment (TypeError: idx.add is not a function)

Tags: javascript, lunrjs

I'm trying to create a lunr index and be able to add documents to it after being assigned. This is a slightly simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```js
var documents = [{
  'id': '1',
  'content': 'hello'
}, {
  'id': '2',
  'content': 'world'
}, {
  'id': '3',
  'content': '!'
}];

var idx = lunr(function() {
  this.ref('id');
  this.field('content');
});

for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; ++i) {
  idx.add(documents[i]);
}
```

This is giving me the following error: TypeError: idx.add is not a function.
I've seen multiple [tutorials](http://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2015/04/18/how-i-added-search-to-my-site-with-lunr-dot-js/) saying this is how you're supposed to be able to do it.

It only works for me though if I add the documents when assigning idx;

```js
var documents = [{
  'id': '1',
  'content': 'hello'
}, {
  'id': '2',
  'content': 'world'
}, {
  'id': '3',
  'content': '!'
}];

var idx = lunr(function() {
  this.ref('id');
  this.field('content');

  for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; ++i) {
    this.add(documents[i]);
  }
});
```

I'm still a javascript noob so this might not be related to lunr necessarily.

Comment: When you ask a question, show the common courtesy of checking back in for the answer.

Comment: Hi @user3163192 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @OliverNightingale, sorry for the delay, I clicked on the checkmark now. Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The tutorial you linked to is for an older version of Lunr. The latest version requires you to add all documents to the index within the function you pass to the `lunr` function. In other words, your second example is correct for the latest version of Lunr.

There is a [guide](https://lunrjs.com/guides/upgrading.html) on upgrading to the latest version which should hopefully cover the difference between the old versions from that (and other) tutorials and the latest version.

Comment: @RoyPrins I'm glad it helped you out, and thanks for the upvote!

Comment: Hi @OliverNightingale, thanks for the answer and sorry for not upvoting it. I'm just a complete noob at Stackoverflow

Comment: @OliverNightingale, also I seem to be such a noob that StackOverflow won't allow me to upvote it :S I don't have enough "reputation" apparently

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you on your way towards understanding the platform, although I fail to see how my criticism on common courtesy could be perceived as "unjust". Enjoy stackoverflow and please consider helping others out as well.

Comment: @OliverNightingale thanks for lunrjs (& elasticlunr), you might consider updating the index.html, as it currently suggests the old method of adding the files

Comment: @User632716 which `index.html` are you talking about? If you can provide a link I'll fix it.

Comment: @User632716 oh wow, that is old, hasn't been updated in over three years now. It is the _old_ homepage when it was hosted on gh pages. I'll get round to removing some of the old cruft from the repo.

Answer (score -1):

I have same error, you have to use old v1.0.0 to do so.

v1.0

```
                  `var idx = lunr(function () {
                     this.ref('id')
                       this.field('text')
                     })


  // somewhere else, when you received 1 json from a stream.
 oboe().node('features.*', function( ___feature___ ){
                                 idx.add( one-node-json)
                     )}
```

`

v2.x you can not do that, In 2.x the documents are added before the end of the configuration function

```
      `var idx = lunr(function () {
                    this.ref('id')
                   this.field('text')

               // at this moment you have to have whole json,  not work with oboe stream json
               // when stream json, only 1 node received at a time, you do not have whole-json yet 
                //until you reach stream end
                this.add( whole-json)
               })`
```

To avoid store whole 1GB json in memory, I choose oboe to stream json, means, only 1 piece of json emit at a time, I can only use v1.x to add this one piece json to idx.

v2.x, I have to store those 1 piece of json one by one until end, add up to 1 GB in memory, at that time, I can add whole 1GB json to idx, NOT WORK, since many user's browser will crash at 1GB in memory.

But v1.x will works, since it use lot less memory, by only add 1 piece json at a time.

[I have ask author to solve this in future](https://github.com/olivernn/lunr.js/issues/437)

[v1 v2 difference](https://lunrjs.com/guides/upgrading.html)